# Element in the appended table is always duplicate when add new element to firebase-database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After adding a new element to the firebase-database, the appended HTML table's all elements have been duplicated.

I've tried to fix it using below code snippets. but it is not working.

```
var userlistings = document.querySelectorAll('userlisting')

    for(var i = 0; i < userlistings.length; i++){

    userlistings[i].remove();

    }
```

and

```
createElementWithText('userlisting');
```

Here is the full code.

```
var dbRefUsers = firebase.database().ref().child('Web App').child('Users');

  dbRefUsers.on('value', gotData, errData); 

 function gotData(data){     

    var userlistings = document.querySelectorAll('userlisting')

    for(var i = 0; i < userlistings.length; i++){

    userlistings[i].remove();

    }

    var users = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(users)

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        var k = keys[i];

        var userName = users[k].Name;
        var userEmail = users[k].Email;
        var userPassword = users[k].Password;

    console.log(userName, userEmail, userPassword);

   var appendingTo = document.getElementById("userlist");

   function createElementWithText(tag, text) {
    var elm = document.createElement(tag);
    elm.textContent = text;
    return elm;
    }

   var tr = document.createElement('tr');

   createElementWithText('userlisting');

   tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userName));
   tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userEmail));
   tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userPassword));
   appendingTo.appendChild(tr);

    }
 }
```

Could anyone please help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're listening for a `value` event on `/Web App/Users`:

```
var dbRefUsers = firebase.database().ref().child('Web App').child('Users');
dbRefUsers.on('value', gotData, errData);
```

When you attach this listener your `gotData` is called straight away with a snapshot of all data under `/Web App/Users`. And then whenever something changes under there, `gotData` is called again with a snapshot of the latest data. So this latest snapshot contains the original data *and* the changes.

There are two main ways to deal with this:

1. Clear the UI before rerendering it
2. Listen to child events and perform granular updates

#### Clear the UI before rerendering it

The simplest approach is to make your `userlist` element empty each time `gotData` is called with something like:

```
document.getElementById("userlist");
appendingTo.innerHTML = "";
```

This will work, but you end up rerendering mostly the same elements, which may cause some unnecessary flicker. Not surprisingly, there is a way to fix this by...

#### Listen to child events and perform granular updates

Since you listen for the `value` event, Firebase gives you a snapshot of all data under the location. You can also listen for events one level lower, in which case Firebase will tell you when for example a user has been added.

A good starting point for that is to listen for `child_added`:

```
var appendingTo = document.getElementById("userlist");

dbRefUsers.on('child_added', gotNewChild, errData); 

function gotNewChild(userSnapshot){     
  var user = userSnapshot.val();

  var userName = user.Name;
  var userEmail = user.Email;
  var userPassword = user.Password;

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

  tr.id = userSnapshot.key

  tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userName));
  tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userEmail));
  tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userPassword));

  appendingTo.appendChild(tr);
}
```

A few things to note here:

- There is no loop inside `gotNewChild`, since it gets called for each individual child/user node.
- I set `tr.id = snapshot.key`, so that you can later look up the `tr` for a user by its key with `var userElm = document.getElemenyById(userSnapshot.key)`
- This code won't work:

  ```
  var userlistings = document.querySelectorAll('userlisting')
  for(var i = 0; i < userlistings.length; i++){
     userlistings[i].remove();
  }
  ```

  I removed the (need for this) code, but I highly recommend that you learn to troubleshoot this type of code yourself. I recommend setting a breakpoint on the `for` line and running the code in a debugger. If you inspect `userlistings`, you will see that it contains nothing. This is because you don't do anything with `createElementWithText('userlisting')`. If you're looking to remove the `tr` elements, you need to select them with `document.querySelectorAll('#userlist > tr')`.

Comment: I have refactored my code according to your guidance.

The duplicate element problem solved. But appended table only appear the first `<td>` element   ( which  is `tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userName)); ` )

So how to avoid this situation, sir?

Comment: I don't think the code I shared could be causing that. See if you can reproduce it in a small snippet of code without Firebase. The less code the better, as long as it still reproduces the problem. If you can, post a new question with just that code. This is known as a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and goes a long way to efficiently getting help here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you please refactor above code snippet for change `td` element's attribute like bgcolor?

Comment: Are you asking [How to change the background color of an HTML element from JavaScript](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+change+the+background+color+of+an+HTML+element+from+JavaScript)?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know how to change some attributes on the appended tag. But problem solved by below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169152/how-to-add-inner-attributes-to-appended-tag-elementappended-data-to-table-from/54169289#54169289 But anyway, Thank you for your concern on my problem.