# How to add inner attributes to appended tag element(appended data to table from firebase database)?

Tags: javascript, html

In here, I'm trying to change the inner attributes of the appended button element.

I try it with `innerHtml` property. But it doesn't give me the expected result.

Here is my code snippet.

```
function userAction(){

  }

    function createElementWithText(tag, text) {
    var elm = document.createElement(tag);
    elm.textContent = text;
    return elm;
  }

    function createElementWithAttributeText(tag, text, attribute) {
    var elm = document.createElement(tag);
    elm.textContent = text;
    elm.innerHTML = attribute;
    return elm;
    }


   var tr = document.createElement('tr');
   var td = document.createElement('td');
   var button = document.createElement('button');



   tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userName));
   tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userEmail));
   tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userPassword));
   tr.appendChild(createElementWithAttributeText('button', 'Reveiew', 'type="button" onclick="userAction()" class="btn btn-primary mt-4"'));
```

Actually, my expectation is `<button type="button" onclick="userAction()" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Review</button>`.

But the result is `<button>type="button" onclick="userAction()" class="btn btn-primary mt-4"</button>`.

Could anyone please help me with this concern?

Comment: Please make sure you add the correct tags on your question. I removed the firebase tags because there is nothing in your question about firebase. Having the right tags on your question makes sure it gets to people most likely to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
function userAction(){

  }

    function createElementWithText(tag, text) {
    var elm = document.createElement(tag);
    elm.textContent = text;
    return elm;
  }

    function createElementWithAttributeText(tag, text, attribute) {
    var elm = document.createElement(tag);
    elm.textContent = text;
    elm.innerHTML = attribute;
    return elm;
    }


   var tr = document.createElement('tr');
   var td = document.createElement('td');
   var button = document.createElement('button');



   tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userName));
   tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userEmail));
   tr.appendChild(createElementWithText('td', userPassword));
   var newbtn=document.createElement('button')
   newbtn.setAttribute('type','button')
   newbtn.setAttribute('onclick',userAction)
   newbtn.setAttribute('class','btn btn-primary mt-4')
   newbtn.innerHTML='Review'
   tr.appendChild(newbtn)
```

I hope that this will help you!

Comment: It should small change which is `var newbtn=document.createElement('button')` Anyway, it works fine. Thank you